# Adding PHP Problems

Tags: php

Below I have a lot of Adding and values being created with PHP.

It all works fine! And it can be seen in action here: http://universitycompare.com

EXCEPT - the first set of PHP that has '$totalcost' in it. I can't seem to work out why my values created further below cannot be used to create a total.

Any opinions?

```
<?php
$totalcost = $totalcost2 + $totalcost3; 
$totalcost2 = $li444 + $tuitionTotal;
$totalcost3 = $li4 + $li44;
?>

<!-- WORKING OUT TOTAL TCE -->

<p>
<b class="TCE">
<?php echo $totalcost; ?>
<?php echo array_sum($a); ?>
</b> 
</p>

<!-- END OF WORKING OUT TOTAL TCE -->

<br /><br />
<h2>
Below is a a breakdown of the total cost of Education:
</h2>

<?php
$li2 = get_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');
$li3 = ($li2 * 28) * 2.1;
$li4 = $li3 * 3;
?>

<div class="TCE">
<br />
<h2>Average spent on socialising</h2>
<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Average drink cost</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo the_field('average_drink_price'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure per night</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li2; ?></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li3;?><!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
<li><span>Average drinks spenditure for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li4;?><!-- JAVA BIT --></li>
</ul>

<?php
$li22 = (get_field('average_housing_costs_per_week') * 4 );
$li33 = $li22 * 12;
$li44 = $li33 * 3;
?>

<h2>Average spent on living costs</h2>
<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Housing per week</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo the_field('average_housing_costs_per_week'); ?></li>
<li><span>Housing per month</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li22; ?></li>
<li><span>Housing per year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li33; ?></li>
<li><span>Housing for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li44; ?></li>
</ul>

<div class="clear"></div>   
<p><br /></p>

<?php
$li222 = (get_field('average_shopping_trip_price') * 2.25 );
$li333 = $li222 * 12;
$li444 = $li333 * 3;
?>

<h2>Average spent on food shopping</h2>
<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Average shopping trip </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo the_field('average_shopping_trip_price'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average shopping for the month</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li222; ?></li>
<li><span>Average shopping for the year</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li333; ?></li>
<li><span>Average shopping for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $li444; ?></li>
</ul>

<?php
$tuitionClass = (get_field('tuition_fees') /28 );
$tuitionTotal = (get_field('tuition_fees') * 3 );
?>

<h2>Average spent on tuition</h2>
<ul class="TCE">
<li><span>Price per Week</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $tuitionClass; ?></li>
<li><span>Average tuition fee</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo the_field('tuition_fees'); ?></li>
<li><span>Average tuition fee for 3 years</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;£<?php echo $tuitionTotal; ?></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: If i understand what your question is you should add the 2 totalcosts after you've given them a value, not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked it out as it seems I didn't know defining totals before was not possible, some strange reason I thought it would relay it back, lesson learned!

```
<?php
// AVERAGE DRINK COSTS 
$li2 = get_field('average_drinks_spenditure_per_night');
$li3 = ($li2 * 28) * 2.1;
$li4 = $li3 * 3;

// HOUSING COSTS 
$li22 = (get_field('average_housing_costs_per_week') * 4 );
$li33 = $li22 * 12;
$li44 = $li33 * 3;

// SHOPPING COSTS 
$li222 = (get_field('average_shopping_trip_price') * 2.25 );
$li333 = $li222 * 12;
$li444 = $li333 * 3;

// TUITION FEES 
$tuitionClass = (get_field('tuition_fees') /28 );
$tuitionTotal = (get_field('tuition_fees') * 3 );

// PHP TCE 
$totalcost2 = $li444 + $tuitionTotal;
$totalcost3 = $li4 + $li44;
$totalcost = $totalcost2 + $totalcost3; 
?>
```

This is what I used in the end and just put that before any of the values needed to echo'd.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer, glad you fixed!

Answer (score 1):

PHP scripts are executed **from top to bottom**. You cannot just calculate with variables before defining their values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem. You appear to be trying to print the $totalcost value *before* the $totalcost2 (awful name btw!) and $totalcost3 have been calculated... These are only set at the bottom of your script and thus will only be available at that point. If you want these values printed at the top of your page, then you will need to buffer all your html into a string (rather than dumping it to the client) and once you've got your values, dump them out followed by your captured string of html for the rest of the page. Does that make sense? Does is tackle your question??

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the components after you define the whole.

It should be like this instead:

```
$totalcost2 = $li444 + $tuitionTotal;
$totalcost3 = $li4 + $li44;
$totalcost = $totalcost2 + $totalcost3; 
//This line should only come after $totalcost2 and 3 were defined!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your adding them before they have a value.

```
<?php
$totalcost2 = $li444 + $tuitionTotal;
$totalcost3 = $li4 + $li44;
$totalcost = $totalcost2 + $totalcost3; 
?>
```

Comment: But he needs to move this to the _bottom_ of his script because $li444 is calculated in the body. I guess he wants the totalcost to be a headline, so bottling up the construction of his page into string, then calculating the total, printing the total and then printing the page buffered into the string is the way to achieve the page he wants.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, the PHP interpreter procedurally works its way through a PHP file line by line, and allocates variables into memory as they are parsed by the interpreter. Since you have not yet defined `$totalcost2` and `$totalcost3` when you attempt to sum them together, the PHP interpreter has no reference to any values and cannot sum them.

If you put this initial code block at the bottom of your page, I imagine it would work as you're expecting.